# Changing language in Windows XP doesn't have an effect

Tags: windows, windows-xp

My Windows XP language is set to English. I want Polish as default though. Here is what I did:

1. In the Control Panel's language settings I added Polish and set it as a default. Everything looks okay, but…
2. When I save changes, close the dialog and reopen it, there is no Polish language added.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you want to change user interface's language or keyboard layout?

Comment: A restart of your PC after this change is made will probably make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Windows to stop being in English, and start being in Polish, follow these steps:

Note, that you will need to be the administrator on the PC.

1. [Go here and download the Windows XP Service Pack 3 installer in Polish](http://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/download/details.aspx?id=10767), but do **NOT** run it (yet).
2. Open the Registry Editor by opening the "Run..."-box (<kbd>Start</kbd> → <kbd>Run</kbd> – or just press <kbd>[image] (Windows)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and then typing `regedit`.
3. In the left panel, navigate to

   ```
    HKEY_Local_Machine > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > NIs > Language
   ```
4. In the left panel, right-click `Language` and select `Export`. Save the `.reg` file somewhere you will remember the location of – this file is important, as it serves as your backup, in case something gets messed up!
5. After highlighting the `Language` option in the left panel, you should see a whole bunch of four-symbol codes in the right panel. Scrolling to the very bottom of the right panel, should make you see two options, `Default` and `InstallLanguage` – right click these two values, and select `Modify`.

   Now type in the numerical value for the Polish version of Windows - 0415. Now do the same for the other value (depending on which one you chose first).
6. Now restart your PC (it will not work if you do not restart the PC).
7. After restarting the PC, run the Service Pack 3 installer, you downloaded earlier.
8. Upon successful installation of Service Pack 3, restart your PC (once more).
9. After the restart, Windows should now (largely) be in Polish! There may be some features that are still in English, but for the large parts Windows should now be in Polish.
10. [Here is full list of the language-codes](http://jekkilekki.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/changing-os-languages-in-windows-xp/) (as well as the guide I "stole" this from).

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Click on `Date, Time, Language, and Regional Options`, and then click `Regional and Language Options`.
3. Click on `Regional and Language` options.
4. Change all the language options to the language of your choice or sometimes you have to put the country that speaks that language.
5. Change tabs and do the same.
6. Click on <kbd>OK</kbd>.
7. Close all the windows.
8. Restart the computer.

You can also refer to [this article from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-xp/help/setup/set-up-multiple-languages-windows-xp/).

Comment: The question says this is already done. Also, the link is broken. Finally, this erroneous answer changes the regional options, not the language itself.